# Is it possible to get overflow in Point values?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get the points of a polygon placed on the canvas. I use two nested foreach loops to do this. For a while, the points values printed seem to be right. However, they then randomly change and start printing really huge numbers.

I was wondering if its possible that there is an overflow system for points as well (like integers)?

OUTPUT:

Seemingly correct values:

```
(1st polygon) polygon with 3 points consists of: 456.052846081402,440.563719108395 , 288.468556739137,626.462219126099 , 123.170153242781,438.528230330192
(2nd polygon) polygon with 3 points consists of: 299.570190710352,822.113209251473 , 457.567502547491,630.483784090951 , 633.517910276476,805.773376352209
```

Random/incorrect values:

```
(1st polygon) polygon with 3 points consists of: 21789.3868304564,21788.5641463545 , 21621.8025411141,21974.4626463722 , 21456.5041376178,21786.5286575763
(2nd polygon) polygon with 3 points consists of: 21634.0541308582,22172.1999782293 , 21788.900457968,21978.0155243827 , 21967.6904229818,22150.4079126876
```

Code:

```
public void DefiningPolygonArea()
    {
        foreach (var polygon1 in this.PlayingCanvas.Children.OfType<Polygon>())
        {
            foreach (var polygon2 in this.PlayingCanvas.Children.OfType<Polygon>().Where(x => x != polygon1))
            {
                bool overlaps = HelperMethods.PointCollectionsOverlap_Fast(getPoints(polygon1), getPoints(polygon2));
            }
        }
    }
private List<Point> getPoints(Polygon poly)
    {
        if (poly.Points.Count == 4)
        {
            var transform = poly.TransformToVisual(this.PlayingCanvas);

            Point point1 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[0]);
            Point point2 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[1]);
            Point point3 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[2]);
            Point point4 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[3]);

            area1.Clear();
            area1.Add(point1);
            area1.Add(point2);
            area1.Add(point3);
            area1.Add(point4);
            //Console.WriteLine("polygon with 4 points consists of: " + point1 + " , " + point2 + " , " + point3 + " , " + point4);

        }
        else if (poly.Points.Count == 3)
        {
            var transform = poly.TransformToVisual(this.PlayingCanvas);

            Point point1 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[0]);
            Point point2 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[1]);
            Point point3 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[2]);

            area1.Clear();
            area1.Add(point1);
            area1.Add(point2);
            area1.Add(point3);

            //Console.WriteLine("polygon with 3 points consists of: " + point1 + " , " + point2 + " , " + point3);
        }
        return area1;
    }
```

Comment: It would help us give you an answer if you post your code

Comment: I edited my post to show the code as well now

Comment: What do you mean by: "For a while, the points values printed seem to be right"? For a few runs of the foreach loops? A couple of executions of the entire code?

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear, I meant for a few runs of the foreach loops

Comment: The incorrect values do not seem random. In fact, they seem shifted somehow (distance between x coordinates of two polygons is almost the same, similar for y coordinates).

Comment: How can the points be so huge though? I thought on a canvas its from like 0-1000 for both the x and y values. When I place the shape towards the top and left of the canvas, it initially has lower x and y values close to 0. In contrast, when I place it towards the bottom and right of the canvas, they go up to 900 something. And then after a few runs of the loops, the huge values start printing.

Comment: Is it possible that you have polygons that are not on the canvas, hidden or something like that? Does your code move the polygons (or change the canvas) while you are printing the coordinates? Do you call this after the LayoutUpdated event occurs or before?

Comment: 1.) No, I don't have any hidden polygons on the canvas. I'm actually working with tangibles and Pixelsense so whenever I place a physical 'polygon' object on the screen, it draws a virtual polygon to map the physical object. So unless a physical object is placed on, no polygons can be drawn. So that's why I can't have any hidden ones.

Comment: 2.) The code doesn't move the polygons, but they can get drawn/moved to a new location if the physical object is moved to that location and ideally the point values should just change to the new ones. 3.) I call it within my UpdateVisuals() method so that's whenever a polygon is drawn, it's supposed to get polygon points and check for overlap.